# How to remove all entries containing particular string from history command in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell, password, command-history

Is there any command or way to remove all entries from history of bash shell containing a particular string? this will be useful to remove commands in history containing password.
I know we can remove each history entry by its number but the issue is it deletes only one entry at a time and I need to take out number each time to remove a new entry.

eg. History command shows 5 entries containing password abcabc and I want to remove all the entries from history command containing string abcabc

```
975  2019-03-15 11:20:30 ll
  976  2019-03-15 11:20:33 ll cd
  977  2019-03-15 11:20:36 ll CD
  978  2019-03-15 11:20:45 chown test1:test1 CD
  979  2019-03-15 11:20:53 chown test1:test1 ./CD
  980  2019-03-15 11:20:57 chown test1:test1 .\CD
  981  2019-03-15 11:22:04 cd /tmp/logs/
  982  2019-06-07 10:36:33 su test1
  983  2019-08-22 08:35:10 su user1
  984  2019-08-22 08:35:15 /opt/abc/legacy.exe -password abcabc
  985  2019-09-24 07:20:45 cd /opt/test1/v6r2017x
  986  2019-09-24 07:20:46 ll
  987  2019-09-24 07:21:18 cd /tmp/
  988  2019-09-24 07:21:19 ll
  989  2019-09-24 07:21:24 cd linux_a64/
  990  2019-09-24 07:21:25 /opt/abc/legacy.exe -password abcabc
  991  2019-09-24 07:24:03 cd  build/
  992  2019-09-24 07:24:04 ll
  993  2019-09-24 07:24:07 cd ..
  994  2019-09-24 07:24:10 /opt/abc/legacy.exe -password abcabc
  995  2019-09-24 07:24:15 cd someapp/bin
  996  2019-09-24 07:24:21 ll
  997  2019-09-24 07:24:33 cd .
  998  2019-09-24 07:24:35 cd ..
  999  2019-09-24 07:24:36 ll
```

Tried following command which gave error as given below

```
servername:~ # sed -i 'g/abcabc/d' /home/user1/.bash_history
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

Expectation : No error and all the entries containing string abcabc should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `sed` to remove entries from `.bash_history`.
But as it's a password to avoid typing the password again in the CLI I would advise you to edit your `.bashrc` file and insure that the line with `HISTCONTROL` is set to `ignoreboth` or `ignorespace`. This would allow you to type command in `bash` and not put them in history if they start by a space:

```
promtpt:$ sed -i '/abcabc/d' /home/user/.bash_history
```

Notice the space between `$` and the command this would make the line ignored in bash history.

`-i`: means edit file inline.
`d` in the end mean remove line containing expression between `/`.

This solution only works on Linux `GNU sed`.

Comment: Isn't the history sometimes not written immediately, such that some pending writes to it might be pending, overwriting changes made to the file directly?

Comment: Hi Kiwy, I tried your command but its gving me error as given below sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

Comment: @AmolPatil could you post the full command you typed ?  and add edit your question so I can help you better

Comment: @Kiwy Hi, I have added an example with the error in the question as requested by you.

Comment: @AmolPatil I'm so sorry, delete command for sed do not need `g` flag. it should now work

Comment: Hi Kiwy, still no success. I do not get any error but no change in history as well. Do I need to run this command as root user?

Comment: you have to quit all bash session of root before and quit your bash session once executed. @AmolPatil

Comment: Hi, Seems to be difficult as other people from environment team will be accessing the shared servers so I can not ask them to quit and also it will not be guaranteed that no one will start session once I execute the command as other vendors are also involved. But still I will try with root and update here..

Comment: how and why do they share the same user is a question you should ask in this case. You should think about enforcing  the use of `sudo` and no longer allow root connection except for the super admin.

Comment: @AmolPatil You need to exit bash for any changes to ~/.bash_history to take affect. "history" is the current history in memory. To confirm changes took affect use `cat ~/.bash_history | grep yourstring` if nothing shows, sed did its job.

Comment: AFAIR there's a lot of situations when this won't work due to a plethora of events causing Bash to overwrite `~/.bash_history` with current memory version, depending on its configuration. It gets even more complicated when you use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`, or simply open multiple Bash sessions in several virtual terminals at once. It's not a bad solution but it's specific, whereas using `history` command is a general solution (as far as it comes to Bash at least - I think `history` was supposed to be universal in all POSIX shells but it was never standardized, DQMOT).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but I just did it in a loop like so:

```
for ln in $( history | grep my_phrase | cut -f2 -d' '); do
    history -d $ln
done
```

- `$(...)` - command substitution, returns `stdout` of `...`
- `cut -f2 -d' '` - cuts 2nd column of space delimited output, i.e. line number
- `history -d $ln` - removes given line number from history

One liner for easy copy&paste:

```
for ln in $( history | grep my_phrase | cut -f2 -d' '); do history -d $ln; done
```

Comment: To avoid 'history position out of range' error you could add 'tac' command to the piped command:    
`for ln in $( history | tac | grep my_phrase | cut -f2 -d' '); do history -d $ln; done`

Comment: Hmm. It's been a while since I used Bash but I think by default if you make a space before a command it won't be added to the history. That's why I put a space at the beginning of that subshell call - to avoid the "out of range" error. If it doesn't work, though, then yes, absolutely, your solution will - good job.

Answer (score 1):

Another one similar to @cprn's answer but using `awk` (rather than `cut`) and a function:

```bash
function del_word_history () {
  if [ -z "${1}" ]; then return false; fi
  mapfile -t result <<< "$(history | grep "${1}" | tac | awk '{print $1}')"
  for idx in "${result[@]}"; do
    history -d $idx
  done
}
```

- `tac` inverts the lines of the output (some posts pointed out it's not common to all systems)
- `[-z $1 ]`: `true` if first argument passed to the function (`$1`) is empty.
- `mapfile -t` ([man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/mapfileh.html); [some guides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mapfile-command-in-linux-with-examples/)): reads `stdin` into an array variable (`result`)

  - `"${result[@]}"` returns the array
- `awk '{print $1}'` ([GNU users guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), [brief guides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/), [man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/awk1.html)): used for both: identifying a match and processing it. It splits the data delimited by whitespace (default) and stores it in the `$n` variables.
- `'{pring $1}'` reads for *perform `print` action on first word*.

**Usage:**

```
del_word_history history
del_word_history abcabc
history -w
```

---

The below is a **cleaner solution** that checks if we obtained the `idx` number of the `history`, rather than some other word of a multi line entry:

```bash
function del_word_history () {
  if [ -z "${1}" ]; then return false; fi
  mapfile -t lines <<< "$(history | grep "${1}" | tac)"
  for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    idx="$(printf '%s' "${line}" | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { print $1 } }')"
    if [ -n "${idx}" ]; then
      echo "removing line ${idx}"
      history -d $idx
    fi
  done
}
```

The main differences are:

- we get the full lines in the array variable `lines` via `mapfile`
- `awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) { print $1 }}'` checks that the first word of each line is a number, and it `stdout`s that same first word (and gets to the `idx` variable)
- `[ -n ${idx}" ] just checks if` idx` is not empty